# A calculus problem from high school textbook

Tags: calculus, derivatives, applications

A man 150 cm tall, walks away from a source of light situated at the top of a pole 5 m high at the rate of 0.7 m/s. Find the rate at which:

1. his shadow is lengthening
2. the tip of his shadow is moving

when he is 2 m away from pole.

**My attempt:** I found the rate at which his shadow is lengthening by using the property of similar triangles and by differentiating. However, for the 2nd part, I could not figure out the rate to be found. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: As a hint for part 2, you should consider the distance of the tip of the shadow from the base of the pole.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) [Please use MathJax.](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) For some basic information about writing math at this site, see [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189). Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for writing a good question.  More specifically, please show us your calculations, so that we can help you by spotting out the possible mistakes.

Comment: This seems to be (abstractly) a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2010673/29335) and probably more. Does anyone know if we have a canonical abstract duplicate for this?

Answer (score 0):

Denote the distance of the man from the pole by $l$ and the length of the shadow by $s$. You are given $l'=0.7\ m/s$ and were asked to find $s'$ which you already have. What you are looking for is the rate of change of $l+s$, i.e., you need to find $(l+s)'=l'+s'$. Answer should be ready from there.

Answer (score 0):

Let x= Distance of person from the bottom of the Pole,  and y=Distance of shadow tip from person's position
$\frac{y}{x+y}=\frac{1.5}{5}$,  therefore $7y=3x$,  
Now rate of shadow lengthening is $\frac{7dy}{dt}=\frac{3dx}{dt}$ 
$\frac{7dy}{dt}=3 (0.7)$
$\frac{dy}{dt}=0.3 m/s$
Rate at which shadow tip is moving is
 $\frac{d(x+y}{dt}=\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{dy}{dt}=0.7+0.3=1 m/s$